# How to change the color of S5 Flex menu black to any other? (Joomla 1.6 S5 Shoppingbag)

Tags: apache-flex, joomla, menu, s5

I'm trying to change the color of top menu, it looks like a gradient and I can't find any document which contains any color of background menu or a picture of it.

Comment: I think this question would benefit from some more context.  You need to change the color of what top menu?  Where does this menu show up?  What technologies are you using?  What is S5? How does Flex relate to your question?

Comment: A link to your site would be nice so it can be tested in a developer tool. Why on earth are you using Joomla 1.6? Are you not aware of how outdated and the security risks, not to mention you're missing out on many more features with Joomla 2.5? You should update ASAP!

Answer (score 0):

Just change Highlight 1 color in Theme Specific selection.
Extension/Template Manager/your name of theme/Vertex/Theme Specific

[image]